# Why does the timestamp format change after I fetch it from table?

Tags: mysql, timestamp, python

My table's structure:

```
+------------+---------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field      | Type          | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+------------+---------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| f_id       | bigint(20)    | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| f_uid      | bigint(20)    | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| f_phone    | char(32)      | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| f_username | char(64)      | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| f_amount   | decimal(16,8) | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| f_unspent  | decimal(16,8) | NO   |     | 0.00000000        |                |
| f_number   | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| f_left     | int(11)       | NO   |     | 0                 |                |
| f_coin     | int(11)       | NO   |     | 0                 |                |
| f_message  | varchar(128)  | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| f_accurate | int(11)       | NO   |     | 0                 |                |
| f_type     | int(11)       | NO   |     | 0                 |                |
| f_status   | int(11)       | NO   |     | 0                 |                |
| f_created  | timestamp     | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
| f_key      | char(64)      | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
+------------+---------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

My sample data:

```
+------+--------+---------------------+
| f_id | f_uid  | f_created           |
+------+--------+---------------------+
|    1 | 123456 | 2018-08-14 10:33:52 |
+------+--------+---------------------+
```

And then, when I fetch the `f_created` value via Python API I have a different date format:

```
"Tue, 14 Aug 2018 10:33:52 GMT"
```

Why has happened? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you've retrieved it in python you get a python `datetime` object. How this is printed is up to the `datetime.strptime` / `strftime` functions.

Comment: But I didn't call any functions like `strptime`  or `strftime`. I just `fetchone` and print it out without any processes.

Comment: It would come from the `repr()` method - https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/datetime.py#L1326 as the default mechanism that converts a `datetime` to string.

Comment: I have try to covert it by `str` method, like this `[i.update({"created": str(i.get("created"))}) for i in data]`, and it's works. Thank you for remind!